# How do I right align one column in the results of a LINQPad query?

Tags: css, alignment, linqpad

I have a LINQPad C# Espression query. In the results of that query, I want to right align the data in one column. All other columns should keep the current standard alignment (left aligned).
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Select (x => new { ..., Name = Util.WithStyle (x.Name, "float:right"), ...})
```